# Oracle VPD Session issue with Tomcat JDBC

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, vpd

My goal is to be able to create 'Isolated sessions' using Tomcat JDBC with Oracle VPD. How do I achieve concept similar to [SessionEventAdapter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_Exclusive_Isolated_Client_Sessions_for_Virtual_Private_Database_(ELUG)#CIHJFGFD) in Eclipse Link but with more Tomcat Connection Pool. My current client code below:

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context jndi = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

DataSource ds = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("jdbc/" + _jdbcResource);
_connection = ds.getConnection();

_statement = _connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
```

Resource definition in **Context.xml**

```
<Resource defaultAutoCommit="true" defaultReadOnly="false"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        fairQueue="false" initialSize="10"
        jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;" jmxEnabled="true"
        logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="100"
        maxWait="30000" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="5000"
        minIdle="10" name="jdbc/OracleApps" password="APPS"
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="600"
        testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true"            testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:testmenot:1521:DEV"
        useEquals="false" username="APPS" validationInterval="30000" validationQuery="SELECT 2+2 FROM DUAL"/>
```

Please do let me know if any information is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to set client context by unwrapping connection when using **Tomcat DBCP**

`DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(jndi); 
 Connection conn = ds.getConnection(); 
 if (conn.isWrapperFor(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)) { 
    OracleConnection oraCon=conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
    --Only Context, Parameter name, Parameter Value
    oraCon.setApplicationContext("CLIENTCONTEXT", "ORACLE_USER_ID", userId);`

**Note: Oracle JDBC thin driver supports only one context i.e. CLIENTCONTEXT**